# how to get data from the UIAddressbook in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to import data frome the iphone address book to my applciation.
Can you give me any reference sample code?

Answer (score 1):

(There is no UIAddressBook.)

To get data from the address book, use the AddressBook.framework. See the [*Address Book Programming Guide for iPhone OS*](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744) for a tutorial.