# How to access the phone contact list and display it in tableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, contacts, abaddressbook

Such as the Table cell having:

1. Contact image
2. Contact name.

I found that we have to use framework:

1. AddressBook.framework
2. AddressBookUI.framework

How can I achieve this?

Comment: see this :http://zcentric.com/2008/09/19/access-the-address-book/

Comment: duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744894/how-to-get-data-from-the-uiaddressbook-in-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); // create address book reference object
NSArray *abContactArray = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook); // get address book contact array

NSInteger totalContacts =[abContactArray count];
    
for(NSUInteger loop= 0 ; loop < totalContacts; loop++)
{
    ABRecordRef record = (ABRecordRef)[abContactArray objectAtIndex:loop]; // get address book record
        
   if(ABRecordGetRecordType(record) ==  kABPersonType) // this check execute if it is person group
    {
            ABRecordID recordId = ABRecordGetRecordID(record); // get record id from address book record
            
            NSString *recordIdString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",recordId]; // get record id string from record id
            
            NSString *firstNameString = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(record,kABPersonFirstNameProperty); // fetch contact first name from address book  
            NSString *lastNameString = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(record,kABPersonLastNameProperty); // fetch contact last name from address book
    }
}
```

for more check these links

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Thanx Sadia :) ... It Works for me but still fighting to display contact image :(

Comment: Yuupppp... i got solution to display contact image also for that i use....
NSData *imageData = [(NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(record, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail) autorelease];

Comment: Why can I access contacts in iOS6 without being prompted?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277249/why-can-i-access-the-iphone-address-book-contacts-without-being-prompted