# Why can I access the iPhone address book contacts without being prompted?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, abaddressbook

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil);

ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
    NSArray *folks = (__bridge NSArray *)(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook));
    NSLog(@"%@",folks);
});
```

I'm able to access the contacts with no prompt to the user. Opening Settings > Privacy > Contacts I see no entry for my application. (Running in Simulator)

Comment: Are you running the iOS 6 simulator? You're only asked for permission once per app. Try reinstalling the app.

Comment: I never got asked the first time.
Deleted, still the same thing. I can access my contact data with no prompt not using any deprecated functions.. something's not right.

Don't see it in the General>Privacy section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contacts privacy prompt doesn't work on the simulator. Try it on a device.

Comment: Thanks, just making sure I wasn't missing something!

Comment: Ugh. So it's impossible to test the unprompted case in the simulator?